# Why does ASP.NET Core CacheTagHelper vary-by-route not refresh Cache on route change?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I've got the following controller method defined that creates two different asp.net core routes (named route1 and route2).  I'm expecting that when I use the cshtml below that when I call:

```
localhost/route1
localhost/route2
```

that my cache will be replaced but it is not.

(Having the parameter {param} passed in does not change my expected results)

Controller Page

```
    [Route("/route1/{param}", Name = "route1")]
    public IActionResult Route1(string param)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "route1.";
        return View("CacheTagHelper/vary-by-route");
    }

    [Route("/route2/{param}", Name = "route2")]
    public IActionResult Route2(string param)
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "route2.";
        return View("CacheTagHelper/vary-by-route");
    }
```

View Page

```
<Cache vary-by-route="route1,route2">Time Inside Cache Tag Helper : @DateTime.Now</Cache>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no route value keyed route1/route2. Aka your cache TagHelper should be:

```
<cache vary-by-route="param">Time Inside Cache Tag Helper : @DateTime.Now</cache>
```

Comment: @n-taylor-mullen I'm confused.  vary-by-route does not break cache based on changing the route to the view?  that is, /route1 and /route2 are looked on as the same route?  Can you point me at the source in github that does this? i could not find it.  -thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a good definition for this from on old issue posted to the github repo.

> A comma-separated list of route data parameter names that the result
>   should be varied by. The route data parameter values are used as part
>   of the cache entry key.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1552